# Method missing when running FSharp.Data app

Tags: macos, mono, f#-data

I have a mono/.Net 4.5 app that compiles just fine. But whe I run it I get a Method missing Http.Request. The code in question is this

```
let private post url parser body = 

      let res = Http.Request (
                    url,
                    body = (body |> TextRequest),
                    silentHttpErrors = true,
                    headers = [
                                Accept HttpContentTypes.Json
                                ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json
                              ]
                  )
      let body = 
          match res.Body with
          HttpResponseBody.Text str -> str
          | _ -> failwith "Only text replies are supported"

      if res.StatusCode >= 200 && res.StatusCode < 300 then
          body |> parser
      else
          body |> errorParser
```

It doesn't seem to be related with the actual method because all method calls from FSharp.Data seems to fail.

I'm experiencing this both when running some standard nunit tests or when executing.

Answer (score 0):

I would seem that the issue was that I had FSharp.Data.TypeProviders installed in the GAC. removing that

```
gacutil -u FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
```

solved it